# Using Dell middle trackpad button as middle mouse button?

Tags: laptop, mouse, touchpad

I have one of the various Dell laptops that actually has 5 buttons around the trackpad (a Latitude E5550):

[image: Dell Latitude E5550]

I really like the middle mouse button and use it quite often, so I would like to use the middle button above the trackpad as a middle mouse button.  However, I can't find any way to do it.  Its default function is to allow scrolling with the nipple when held down, but I never use that functionality so I don't care about that.  Also, I'm aware of the "middle click emulation" by holding left and right buttons down at the same time, but it's not really what I want.

I want to be able to map pressing the middle button to a middle click, simple as that.  Using the latest version of the Dell "touchpad properties" software, I look through its interface and I don't see anywhere I can customize the functionality of that middle button.  So is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There it is in the Dell Pointing Devices software. The version is dated Feb. 19, 2015, Windows 8.1 64-bit.

NOTE: this is not particularly clear in the Dell Pointing Devices software, but you *first* have to click on the "Pointstick" image along the top before you will get the option to change the behaviour of the middle button above the touchpad (the two buttons below the touchpad *are* considered part of the touchpad).  Even though it is physically close to the touchpad, the middle button above is *not* considered "part" of the touchpad; it is considered "part" of the Pointstick, so the option to configure that middle button above the touchpad is in the Pointstick settings.  So first click on the Pointstick image along the top, then click Buttons, then you will see the "Middle Button" option.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)  Source: NotebookCheck.net</sup>

Comment: Which laptop model are you using?

Comment: Latitude E5450, got my drivers from Dell.com > Support > Support by product

Comment: That's odd; I am using exactly the same version of the software as you but I get "Both Buttons" instead of "Middle Button" (http://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Wbu.png) - does your laptop have a middle button *beneath* the trackpad, or just above it (as shown in my question's picture)?

Comment: Ahhhh I've just realized what I did wrong!!! I was looking at the touchpad settings, not the Pointstick. I am going to suggest some edits to your answer.

Comment: Yeah, the interface there is a little misleading. I tried to point it out on the screenshot, but it probably requires a note with an explanation, feel free to add one.
Anyway, hope your problem is solved now! )

Comment: Please could you approve the edit I suggested to your answer?

Comment: Does anybody know if it is possible to set it as both to click and scroll?